# MongoDB Mongoose: Querying sub-documents using "_id" property doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have the following documents:

```
{  
   "_id":"562e7c594c12942f08fe4192",
   "shapes":[  
      {  
         "_id":"5bd6c4de95ffe03480ee8796",
         "shape":"square",
         "colors": []
      },
      {  
         "_id":"5bd7a9d2604b760004947833",
         "shape":"circle",
         "colors": []
      }
   ]
},
{  
   "_id":"5bd5ba2ca677cb000469168a",
   "shapes":[  
      {  

         "_id":"5bd7a9e4604b760004947834",
         "shape":"square",
         "colors": []
      },
      {  
         "_id":"5bd6d697975e892464b0ed31",
         "shape":"circle",
         "colors": []
      }
   ]
}
```

By using this code:

```
db.test.aggregate(
  { $match : {
     "shapes.shape": "square"
  }},
  { $unwind : "$shapes" },
  { $match : {
     "shapes.shape": "square"
  }}
)
```

It gives me this result:

```
    {  
       "_id":"562e7c594c12942f08fe4192",
       "shapes":[  
          {  
             "_id":"5bd6c4de95ffe03480ee8796",
             "shape":"square",
             "colors": []
          }
       ]
    },
    {  
       "_id":"5bd5ba2ca677cb000469168a",
       "shapes":[  
          {  

             "_id":"5bd7a9e4604b760004947834",
             "shape":"square",
             "colors": []
          }
       ]
    }
```

But what I want is to get only the first document that would look like this:

```
   {  
       "_id":"562e7c594c12942f08fe4192",
       "shapes":[  
          {  
             "_id":"5bd6c4de95ffe03480ee8796",
             "shape":"square",
             "colors": []
          }
       ]
    }
```

So I tried to use the "_id" property in the subdocument like this:

```
db.test.aggregate(
  { $match : {
     "shapes._id": "5bd6c4de95ffe03480ee8796"
  }},
  { $unwind : "$shapes" },
  { $match : {
     "shapes._id": "5bd6c4de95ffe03480ee8796"
  }}
)
```

But by doing that it would return me an empty array just like this:

```
[]
```

Basically what I want is to use the "_id" property of a specific sub-document in my query so that I can push something on the "colors" array of that specific sub-document. How should I change my query statement that I will be able to use the "_id" property?

Comment: Use `$limit ` stage at the end `db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "shapes.shape": "square"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$shapes"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "shapes.shape": "square"
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  }
])`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet it would be a good work around, but what if I have 10 documents like that and I want to manipulate something on one of those documents? Basically I want get a specific document/sub-document so I can manipulate some data on it. I think I was not very clear on my question so I edited it. I apologize if my question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Cast your `_id` to `ObjectId`. Something like `mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5bd6c4de95ffe03480ee8796")`

Comment: It worked. I see, so the data type of the _id property is not just a regular string and mongoose interpreted "5bd6c4de95ffe03480ee8796"  as a regular string. Could that be the explanation?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

This problem was sovled by @AnthonyWinzlet's *second* comment above.